# Meteor Iron Router Run function when collection changes

Tags: meteor

Im new to Meteor and Im trying to figure out how to run a function after a collection change.

I have a route(iron router) that subscribes to a collection with waitOn. Which just waits for the subscrition to be ready before rendering which is what I want.

```
    waitOn: function () {
        return Meteor.subscribe('collection', this.params._id);
    },
```

Any changes to the collection will be updated on all the clients and rendered automatically.

How would I run a function once the collection has changed?

Comment: You can call [observe changes](http://docs.meteor.com/#observe_changes) or [observe](http://docs.meteor.com/#observe) depending on if you need the whole document on each change. Normally, helpers are used to change the content of the page instead of calling observe directly. I'd recommend explaining in more detail what you wish to accomplish.

Comment: Alright I've tried using a helper it works fine using Meteor.Defer to make changes. I've also tried using onData option on iron router as suggested from the first answer. They both work fine. But which one should I use? and which one works best?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `onData` hook, provided that you're returning that data using the `data` helper. E.g this is what a route may look like

```
this.route('routename',
    path : '/abc',
    waitOn: function () {
        return Meteor.subscribe('collection', this.params._id);
    },
    data: function() {
        return Collection.findOne({_id: this.params.id});
    }
    onData: function() {
         //Do something when the data found by the above changes
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I cant seem to find the onData option hook on the iron router docs. I'm using the data helper which works fine but I still not sure how to run a function after the dom updates from the changes

Comment: @AndreEscudero have a look here: https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router#custom-actions-and-hooks

Comment: Ok So onData works fine using Meteor.Defer to make changes to the dom. Someone suggested using helpers to achieve the same and it works aswell. So Now which one is best to use? or does it matter?

Comment: @AndreEscudero you can use either, onData uses Deps.autorun under the hood, which effectively gives it the same effect as using helpers. If you're displaying data off the dom i'd recommend helpers instead since the code is a bit cleaner